# request for member 'sval' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, lex

I am getting an error in my parser for a toy language I am making. Here is some of my parser code:

```
%union {
  char* <sval>;
}

%token INTEGER
%token INTDEC FLODEC AS
%token <sval> VARIABLE
%token POINT LBRACKET RBRACKET
%token SHOW ESC
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' MODULO FACTORIAL FLOOR
%left '^'

%code requires {
  #define YYSTYPE float
}
```

And some of my lexer code:

```
    as                         {return AS;}
float                      {return FLODEC;}
show                       {return SHOW;}
int                        {return INTDEC;}
esc                        {return ESC;}
\.                         {return POINT;}
{integer}                  {yylval = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER;}
[a-zA-Z]+                  {yylval.sval = strdup(yytext); return VARIABLE;}
["\\"]                     {return FLOOR;}
[-+/=*^\n]                 {return *yytext;}
["("]                      {return LBRACKET;}
[")"]                      {return RBRACKET;}
["!"]                      {return FACTORIAL;}
["%%"]                     {return MODULO;}
[" \t\n"]
.                          {printf("Syntax error");}
```

How do I fix this as I think this is actually in a union but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: You cannot have both `yylval = atoi(yytext);` and `yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);` It is either a union or an integer, not both things at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* <sval>;
```

is not a valid C member declaration, and `%union` members are just C member declarations. (Yacc/bison copies them literally into a `union` declaration.) So attempting to compile that code is bound to produce a compile-time error message in the declaration of the `union YYSTYPE`. Subsequent code will not be able to use `union YYSTYPE` because it has not been correctly declared, and therefore will produce the error message shown.

Moreover, once you have declared that the semantic type is a `union`, your lexical scanner actions need to be adjusted accordingly. You will not be able to compile

```
yylval = strdup(yytext);
```

because `yylval` has type `union YYSTYPE` and a `union` can only be assigned to from another `union` variable of the same type. You'll need to change that to

```
yylval.sval = strdup(yytext);
```

Your other `yylval` assignment will need to be dealt with in the same way, but you don't seem to have appropriate `union` members for them in your `%union` declaration, so you'll have to start by fixing that.